# laravel email media query ignored

Tags: css, laravel, email, media-queries

I have a css class that I apply to elements in my blade template.

It works fine when I have the following css in my themes/default.css

```
.mobile-full-width {
    min-width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    color: red !important;
}
```

but it does not work when I use it together with a media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .mobile-full-width {
        min-width: 100% !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        color: red !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a heads up, media queries are not respected in all email clients; which one are you using to view the emails?

Comment: You're going to want to do some reading about `responsive email templates`. Email clients are behind about 15 years at this point, and nowhere near up to date as the web has become.

Answer (score 0):

You must add your media query css in the layout.blade.php file not in the theme css file so that it could be rendered.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually what solved my issue.